# SSRS Subreport parameters

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008-r2

I have a simple dashboard that keeps track of time sheets and allows me  to see who has missing, or late time sheets. I also have simple parameters like Division, LineOfBusiness, Department, etc... The dashboard gives some overall counts of records.

I have actions set on the boxes with the counts that launches a sub-report which passes the parameters to a detail report. If the action is taken from the dashboard the parameters are passed and the sub-report runs. Even if I change the parameters on the sub-report, they refresh back to what was passed from the parent. If I run the sub-report by itself (so if I run the template itself without passing by the dashboard), I can pick any values I want for the parameters.

When I use the dashboard and run a sub-report by clicking on a box, how can I update the sub-report parameters without SSRS automatically overriding my new sub-report inputs and reverting back to the values passed by the parent parameters?

Comment: does this happen only in the BIDS? did you check in the Report Manager?

Comment: BhupeshC - I have not deployed to Server yet so I don't know if it will do it in Report Manager. I am concerned about releasing this was as users will report as a bug.

Comment: well I have deployed my reports on the report manager and it lets me edit subreport parameters, but not in BIDS.

Comment: Deploying to report manager corrected the issue, that is a really odd occurrence. Thanks for the help BhupeshC.